# Google Admin SDK unauthorized client PHP after 1 time works perfectly

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-admin-sdk

Need help with Google admin SDK. I'm a newbie to google admin SDK. So I am stuck on its showing error while authorizing like:

> { error: "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is
>   unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method" }

Here is my code.

```
<?php 

include_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "base.php";
session_start();
echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");


/************************************************
  Make an API request authenticated with a service
  account.
 ************************************************/
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('service_account.json');

$client->setApplicationName("automate user");
$client->setSubject('admin@******.org');

$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']);

$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
//$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

//header('Location: '.filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    if ($credentials_file = checkServiceAccountCredentialsFile()) {
  // set the location manually
  $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret1.json');
} elseif (getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service_account.json')) {
  // use the application default credentials
  $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
} else {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
  return;
}

$dir = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$user = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
$name = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();


//$results = $dir->users->get('********@****.com');
$name->setGivenName('*****');
$name->setFamilyName('*****');
$user->setName($name);
$user->setHashFunction('SHA-1');
$user->setPrimaryEmail('****@***');
$user->setpassword(hash('sha1','******'));
$user->setchangePasswordAtNextLogin(false);


$results = $dir->users->insert($user);

if($results) {
     echo "New user : ".$results->primaryEmail."";
} else{
     echo " User doesn't exist : ".$email;
}

} 
else {

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    //file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
    $redirect_uri = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. '/google/oauth.php';
    header('Location: '.filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


<?php pageFooter(__FILE__); ?>
```

1st time it works perfectly. After some days I run this code it displays error of `unauthorized_client`. I don't know why this error shows. I already created domain-wide delegation service account. Please help and tell what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can give this github forum a try:

[API access using own credentials (server to server flow)](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/wiki/API-access-using-own-credentials-(server-to-server-flow))

> **Step 1 - Creating OAuth2 credentials**
>
> Follow the steps for the product you're using to generate a service
>   account with a JSON key file, then come back to this page.
>
> **Step 2 - Setting up the client library**
>
> Under the [OAUTH2] section of your adsapi_php.ini file, insert the
>   path to your JSON key file and set the scope for the ads API you're
>   accessing. Insert the email account of the user you want to
>   impersonate as, if any.

Comment: I am using Admin directory API and already created service account with JSON key where I am using the following scopes which are authorized: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member